# How to correctly start and end or animation and changing text from other class flutter

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I am learning flutter and i want to start animation & set App bar title 'syncing' from AlertDialog response(basically from other class) then end animation & set Title again after Async operation.

So currently I am achieving this using GlobalKey and Riverpod(StateNotifier).
Created MainScreen GlobalKey and using that GlobalKey from other class before Async Operation i am Calling

```
mainScreenScaffoldKey.currentState.context
      .read(syncProgressProvider)
      .setSyncing();
```

and ending Animation after async operation:

```
 mainScreenScaffoldKey.currentState.context
      .read(syncProgressProvider)
      .syncProgressDone();
```

code :

```
Map<String, dynamic> dialogResponse = await showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => EditNoteScreen(
          _index,
          _task,
          _color,
          dateTime,
          priority: priority,
        ));
if (dialogResponse != null) {
  mainScreenScaffoldKey.currentState.context
      .read(syncProgressProvider)
      .setSyncing();
  await SaveToLocal().save(context.read(listStateProvider.state));
  await CloudNotes().updateCloudNote(
    task: dialogResponse["task"],
    priority: dialogResponse["priority"],
    dateTime: dateTime.toString(),
    index: dialogResponse["index"],
  );
  mainScreenScaffoldKey.currentState.context
      .read(syncProgressProvider)
      .syncProgressDone();
}
```

and listening variable in AppBar title property in MainScreen

I feel this not right approach or is it?

here are some extra snippet
syncProgressProiver:

```
 class SyncProgressModel extends StateNotifier<bool>{

 SyncProgressModel() : super(false);

 syncProgressDone(){
   state =false;
 }
 setSyncing(){
   state =true;
 }
```

MainScreen AppBar Title

```
Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, child) {
        var syncProgress = watch(syncProgressProvider.state);
        if (!syncProgress) {
          return const Text('To-Do List');
        } else {
          return Row(
            children: [
              const Text('Syncing..'),
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                width: 25,
                height: 25,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  strokeWidth: 2,
                  valueColor: animColors,
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        }
      },
    ),
```

Like this

[image]

Comment: animate what exactly? you mean some fade animation when switching widgets between Text('To-Do List') and the Row widget?

Comment: No sir I just want to show Syncing and CircularProgressBar(changing Colors) until async operation is done. I have added a gif in question. I am starting Animation in initState but it wont show until i change one provider Var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about your animations (you don't actually share any of that logic or what initState are you referring to) but if the only thing you want is to animate the color of the CircularProgressIndicator then you could just create a `StatefulWidget` that does that for you and call it to build only when `syncProgress == true`

```
class AnimatedWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  AnimatedWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AnimatedWidgetState createState() => _AnimatedWidgetState();
}

class _AnimatedWidgetState extends State<AnimatedWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  final Animatable<Color> _colorTween = TweenSequence<Color>([
    TweenSequenceItem<Color>(
      tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.red, end: Colors.amber),
      weight: 20,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<Color>(
      tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.amber, end: Colors.green),
      weight: 20,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<Color>(
      tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.green, end: Colors.blue),
      weight: 20,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<Color>(
      tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.blue, end: Colors.purple),
      weight: 20,
    ),
    TweenSequenceItem<Color>(
      tween: ColorTween(begin: Colors.purple, end: Colors.red),
      weight: 20,
    ),
    
  ]).chain(CurveTween(curve: Curves.linear));

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      animationBehavior: AnimationBehavior.preserve,
      vsync: this,
    )..repeat();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        const Text('Syncing..'),
        Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
          width: 25,
          height: 25,
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            strokeWidth: 2,
            valueColor: _colorTween.animate(_controller)
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and in your consumer just call it, the widget will handle the animation itself

```
Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, child) {
        var syncProgress = watch(syncProgressProvider.state);
        if (!syncProgress) {
          return const Text('To-Do List');
        } else {
          return AnimatedWidget(); //right here
        }
      },
    ),
```

**UPDATE**

> To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a
> reference to the ancestor by calling
> dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's
> didChangeDependencies() method.

What does this means is that you should keep a reference of the objects depending on your context before the context itself is rebuilt (when you call updateValueAt or updateValue in your dialog it rebuild the list and is no longer safe to call context.read)

```
updateCloudNote(BuildContext context) async {
    /// keep the reference before calling the dialog to prevent 
    /// when the context change because of the dialogs action
    final syncProgress = context.read(syncProgressProvider); 
    final listState = context.read(listStateProvider.state);
    Map<String, dynamic> dialogResponse = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => EditNoteScreen(
              _index,
              _task,
              _color,
              dateTime,
              priority: priority,
            ));
    if (dialogResponse != null) {
      //when using GlobalKey didn't get that Widget Ancestor error
      // use the reference saved instead of context.read
      syncProgress.setSyncing();
      await SaveToLocal().save(listState);
      await CloudNotes().updateCloudNote(
        task: dialogResponse["task"],
        priority: dialogResponse["priority"],
        dateTime: dateTime.toString(),
        index: dialogResponse["index"],
      );
      syncProgress.syncProgressDone();
    }
  }
```

What you did combining the providers is basically what you could do inside the same `syncProgressProvider`

```
final syncProgressProvider = StateNotifierProvider<SyncProgressModel>((ref)
    => SyncProgressModel(ref.read));

class SyncProgressModel extends StateNotifier<bool>{
 final saveToLocal saveLocal = SaveToLocal();
 final CloudNotes cloudNotes = CloudNotes();
 final Reader _read;

 SyncProgressModel(this._read) : super(false);

 syncProgressDone(){
   state = false;
 }

 setSyncing(){
   state = true;
 }

 updateCall({int priority, int index, String task, String dateTime}) async {
   state = true;
   await saveLocal.save(_read(listStateProvider.state));
   await cloudNotes.updateCloudNote(
      task: task,
      priority: priority,
      dateTime: dateTime,
      index: index,
   );
   state = false;
  }

}
```

And finally combining the 2 ideas:

```
updateCloudNote(BuildContext context) async {
    /// keep the reference before calling the dialog to prevent 
    /// when the context change because of the dialogs action
    final syncProgress = context.read(syncProgressProvider); 
    Map<String, dynamic> dialogResponse = await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => EditNoteScreen(
              _index,
              _task,
              _color,
              dateTime,
              priority: priority,
            ));
    if (dialogResponse != null) {
      await syncProgress.updateCall(
        task: dialogResponse["task"],
        priority: dialogResponse["priority"],
        dateTime: dateTime.toString(),
        index: dialogResponse["index"],
      );
    }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, and yes animation logic is like that (without chain method) but my Question specifically was, I am using GlobalKey of Mainscreen to change value from other class, like this is that fine `mainScreenKey.currentState.context.read(syncProgressProvider).setSyncing();`   and  to set back todo-list ` mainScreenScaffoldKey.currentState.context
          .read(syncProgressProvider)
          .syncProgressDone();`

Comment: The global key is actually irrelevant when using a provider from riverpod because ProviderScope is at the beginning of your app, just using context.read should be enough

Comment: Yes bu twhen I was using context.read sometimes, yes sometimes I was getting `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
[        ] E/flutter (19530): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.` so then i was using global Key

Comment: Show where are you calling context.read, specially that dialog

Comment: [on line no.27* i am calling context.read & dialog in gist](https://gist.github.com/sujalabhani/23721a9a8c24703bb2c85c3b3ae80063)

Comment: I suppose your custom container depends on listStateProvider to be created in the list view, if you're updating the value that forces a rebuild of the widget and the context is not longer the same, maybe you can do all that logic in EditNoteScreen button instead of returning the map from pop

Comment: Yes it watches listStateprovider.state, okay Understood, well then until async operation is done it will stay on Screen I guess(I was doing that but there was no Animation or Syncing Text) so until async operation is done I can't `Navigator.pop(context)`

Comment: What value do notesProvider and listStateProvider hold? Riverpod is really good to combine states of different providers, you can change syncProgressProvider inside them and avoid all that logic in the onTap

Comment: listStateProvider has ToDo objects and noteProvider has Notes objects , so what you mean is I should watch one provider(inside other). but I tried [like this](https://gist.github.com/sujalabhani/4b24bab465ffa76301b0f5cf73f3f959) it gives me same error(although it works fine,) also any example for saving reference of ancestor ( that you know of?)   `E/flutter (17402): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.`

Comment: it should be fine as long as you keep the reference before opening the dialog, which is where you update the lsit and force a rebuilt of the widget that called the dialog, check the update

Comment: Thank you for the help. yes understood now (should have saved in variable) I am going to do as Combining two ideas says(tested works without any warning or errors), great answer btw.